# Gridview checkbox errer "Object reference is not set to an instance of the object"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, android-activity

On **button1** click i can add check boxes to the **GridView colum**n,

```
        grid_student.DataSource = semDS;
        grid_student.DataBind();
        TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
        grid_student.Columns.Add(tf);

        foreach (GridViewRow gr in grid_student.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
            chk.ID = "chkSelected";
            chk.Checked=true;
            gr.Cells[0].Controls.Add(chk);
        }
```

But the problem is when i click on **button2** 
it says that "object reference is not set to an instance of an object"
code for button2

```
 foreach (GridViewRow grr in grid_student.Rows)
    {
        if (grr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //CheckBox checkB = new CheckBox();
           // checkB = grr.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelected") as CheckBox;
            CheckBox checkB =(CheckBox)grr.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelected");
            if (checkB.Checked)
            {
                Label78.Text = "True";//or whatever i want 
            }
        }
    }
```

actually i know this type of errors are mostly occurred when we are trying to take some null value into an object,
but in this case i have added check boxes successfully.
please reply,
it would be very helpful for me.
 thanks in advance.

Comment: did you debug to check where you getting this exception? i think one of the rows is empty which is causing this exception

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is a common situation for beginner programmers. The link provided should help you understand the problem. Then use the debugger to find what/where/when you have a variable that is `null`.

Comment: in button1 event i m generating checkboxes for each row . and i can see it in my gridview. so the NullRefrenceException should not come in picture.

Comment: @EjazAnsari Because new column doesn't exist.

Comment: yes i got it,but now what should i do for this...i want to add this column dynamically in **code behind**.thanks